# Flex Box aligning items in center instead of left

Tags: html, css, flexbox, magento2

So I am using a `col-3` / `col-12` grid system using a flexbox `.row` to align my items in the product display. For whatever reason when I don't have **four** `col-3`'s in each row it aligns my `.product-display` boxes in the center instead of under the respective columns which would be **left** for this example.

See the attached screenshots for additional details. Also, I tried to make a new row to see if the items would just align to the left however that did not work either.

[How I want them to be aligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7LPo.png)

[Aligns perfectly when 4 products fill the row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCPdl.png)

```css
.product-display .col-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -ms-box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  padding: 0 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 .5rem .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.product-display .row {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.product-name {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.row-spacing {
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.bullet-text {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: left;
}

.caster-series-image {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .caster-series-image {
    max-height: 290px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .col-content {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row flex-wrap">
  <div class="col-3 row-spacing">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/avant-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
      <div class="col-content">
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/avant-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/avant.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-content">
        <ul class="bullet-text">
          <li><b>Capacity:</b> 80-100 lbs</li>
          <li><b>Sizes:</b> 2", 3", 4", 5"</li>
          <li><b>Height:</b> 2 &frac34;" - 3 <sup>7</sup>&#8260;<sub>32</sub>"</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/avant-series.html">
          <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 row-spacing">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/genesis-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
      <div class="col-content">
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/genesis-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/genesis.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-content">
        <ul class="bullet-text">
          <li><b>Capacity:</b> 110-225 lbs</li>
          <li><b>Sizes:</b> 2", 3"</li>
          <li><b>Height:</b> 2" - 5 &frac58;"</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/genesis-series.html">
          <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 row-spacing">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
      <div class="col-content">
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/optimus.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-content">
        <ul class="bullet-text">
          <li><b>Capacity:</b> 140 lbs</li>
          <li><b>Sizes:</b> 2 &frac18;"</li>
          <li><b>Height:</b> 4 <sup>9</sup>&#8260;<sub>32</sub>"</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html">
          <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 row-spacing">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
      <div class="col-content">
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/eclipse.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="col-content">
        <ul class="bullet-text">
          <li><b>Capacity:</b> 120-125 lbs</li>
          <li><b>Sizes:</b> 3", 4"</li>
          <li><b>Height:</b> 4 <sup>5</sup>&#8260;<sub>16</sub>" - 5 &frac58;"</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html">
          <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 row-spacing">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
    <div class="col-content">
      <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/optimus.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="col-content">
      <ul class="bullet-text">
        <li><b>Capacity:</b> 140 lbs</li>
        <li><b>Sizes:</b> 2 &frac18;"</li>
        <li><b>Height:</b> 4 <sup>9</sup>&#8260;<sub>32</sub>"</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/optimus-series.html">
        <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3 row-spacing">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html"><span style="color: #007dbd;">Product</span></a></h3>
    <div class="col-content">
      <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html"><img src="https://casterdepot.com/media/Shepherd/eclipse.jpg" class="caster-series-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="col-content">
      <ul class="bullet-text">
        <li><b>Capacity:</b> 120-125 lbs</li>
        <li><b>Sizes:</b> 3", 4"</li>
        <li><b>Height:</b> 4 <sup>5</sup>&#8260;<sub>16</sub>" - 5 &frac58;"</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="{{config path=" web/secure/base_url "}}/brands/shepherd-casters/casters/eclipse-series.html">
        <button class="cd-button" type="button">Read More</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `justify-content: flex-start;` for positioning the divs on the left side

Comment: margin auto places the item/content in the middle
```
.product-display .row {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margin from the row because this causes the products to have margin on both sides what causes the products to shift to the middle.

Try this css code instead:

```css
.product-display .row {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin: initial;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this did not seem to work. However, I was playing around with it and was able to find a solution. .row-spacing { and added margin: initial; } Can someone let me know if this is a permanent solution where I won't run into problems down the road?

Comment: Hi Kameron. Glad you've found a way to fix it. That's also a proper approach of doing.